# Node.js/request. Как избавиться от ошибки ETIMEDOUT?

Tags: node.js, сервер, tcp, request, timeout

Использую модуль request и делаю 10 запросов асинхронно.. И происходит такая фигня: ошибка

```
 Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
   at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
   at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
   at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1085:14)
 code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
 errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
 syscall: 'connect',
```

Из-за чего эта ошибка?

Медленный интернет или настройки какие то стоят?

Как избавиться от этой ошибки?

Отловить и снова переотправить запрос?? 
или как еще можно, чтоб на производительность/скорость серва сильно не влияло..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока сделал так:

```
 var rq = request(url);

  rq.on('error', function (err) {
if (err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT') {
console.log("ERRORR!!");
rq.end();
callback(err.code);
}});
```